# IOHIDManager not triggering callback for keyboard

Tags: macos, core-foundation, iokit

So I am trying to put together a simple fullscreen OpenGL application using CGL and IOHIDManager in order to learn the lower-level APIs.  Currently, I am creating an OpenGL context and starting it fullscreen.  I am trying to now add keyboard input so I can quit the app.  I've found many similar examples of using IOHIDManager to read keys, but no matter what I do my callback does not fire.

My callback is just a function that prints "here".  I'm not sure where I am going wrong -- I've tried both CFRunLoopGetCurrent() and CFRunLoopMain().  My main is simply a while loop.  What gives?

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef CreateMatchingDictionary(UInt32 usage_page, UInt32 usage) {        
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFNumberRef page_number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &usage_page);            
    CFDictionarySetValue(dictionary, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey), page_number);
    CFRelease(page_number);

    CFNumberRef usage_number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &usage);            
    CFDictionarySetValue(dictionary, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey), usage_number);
    CFRelease(usage_number);

    return dictionary;
}

void CreateInputManager() {
    IOHIDManagerRef hid_manager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matching_dictionary = CreateMatchingDictionary(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard);
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hid_manager, matching_dictionary);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(hid_manager, KeyboardCallback, NULL);

    IOHIDManagerOpen(hid_manager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(hid_manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}

void KeyboardCallback(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDValueRef value) {                                                                                                       
    puts("CALLBACK!");
}

int main() {
    // Commented out CGL context & fullscreen window creation
    CreateInputManager();
    while(true) {
        ;   
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I put CFRunLoopRun() at the end of function CreateInputManager, my callback is called but the function never returns.  How is this supposed to work in a single-threaded CGL app?  Is it a strict requirement that IOHIDManager requires a run loop to function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOKit and HID work via Mach messaging, which in turn is deeply integrated with the runloop mechanism, as you've found. If you really do want to busy-poll, you can use the `CFRunLoopRunInMode` function with a zero timeout to check for events.

You may wish to consider using a CVDisplayLink to invoke your rendering code on every vertical frame refresh instead. The display link's callback will be called from the runloop, so you can leave your main thread running in CFRunLoopRun().

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1385/_index.html for how Apple recommends you structure event handling in OpenGL applications.

Comment: Excellent, so if I choose to busy-poll by setting HID to use CFRunLoopInMode, will there technically be no runloop mechanism in my program?

Comment: Also, thanks for the CVDisplayLink tip, I was aware of the iOS version of that but not the OSX one.

Comment: Well, there will be a runloop mechanism, but you get to choose when the runloop should handle events, and once it's handled all pending events, it'll return from `CFRunLoopInMode` and give control back to your application.

Comment: Actually, won't IOHIDQueueCopyNextValueWithTimeout allow me to busy-poll key state on the main thread without creating a runloop?

Comment: I'm not sure how `IOHIDQueueCopyNextValueWithTimeout`/`IOHIDQueueCopyNextValue` is implemented internally, but it may well work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to create a separate pthread with the `CreateInputManager` function, specify that the IOHIDManager is to schedule the callback on `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` and kick off a run loop on that thread by calling `CFRunLoopRun()`.

I wonder if there is a way to get IOHIDManager to work with plain-old polling instead of these callbacks...